# Spring profiles and Spring Integration namespaces

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to create following spring configuration

```
<beans profile="profile1">
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="sampleId"/>
</beans>

<beans profile="profile2">
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="sampleId"/>
</beans>
```

(jms:outbound-channel-adapter is namespace from spring integration)

When create such context I get duplicated bean ids exception...

Any idea why?

edit.. (active profile is set to profile1)

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an active profile for current context. This token can be set as:

*an Environment Variable*

*a JVM Property*

*Web Parameter*

*Programmatic*

Spring also looks for the token, spring.profiles.default, which can be used to set the default profile(s) if none are specified with spring.profiles.active.

Example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>web-dev</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

where applicationContext looks like:

```
<beans profile="web-dev, test-dev">
        <import resource="trace-context.xml"/>
        <import resource="spring-data-jpa.xml"/>
        <import resource="spring-security-roles.xml" />
    </beans>

    <beans profile="web-dev">
        <bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
                p:location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

        <import resource="spring-cache.xml"/>
        <import resource="tiles-context.xml" />
        <import resource="themes-context.xml" />
    </beans>  

    <beans profile="test-dev">
        <bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
                p:location="classpath:spring.properties" />
    </beans>
```

Comment: Hmmm I've seen something similar but in my case with ActiveMQ schema e.g.  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 179 in XML document from class path resource [au/gov/dha/messagecentre/messagecentre-jms.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 179; columnNumber: 129; cvc-id.2: There are multiple occurrences of ID value 'messageCentreBroker'.  This is with amq: schema inside beans: <beans profile="dev"><amq:broker id="messageCentreBroker" ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all relevant xsd declarations are using >= 3.1 versions.  Profiles feature was added in Spring version 3.1.  At a minimum set for beans and jms namespaces.  See also my answer to a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003965/993262).