# Loading util:properties with Spring Profile causes multiple occurrences of ID

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

I am using Spring(3.1) profiles to load property files vis util:properties:

```
<beans profile="local">
    <util:properties id="myProps"  
                     location="classpath:local.properties" />
</beans>
<beans profile="dev">
    <util:properties id="myProps"  
                     location="classpath:dev.properties" />
</beans>
```

And I invoke the profile via a runtime parameter(running on TC Server):`-Dspring.profiles.active=local`

But I get the error `There are multiple occurrences of ID value 'myProps'`

This was running previously with other bean definitions but once the `util:properties` was added I get the error.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: On starting up the web application, whilst Spring is loading it's context and wiring beans.

Comment: Double check that there is no 3th bean with this Id.

Comment: If I use a single bean in one profile, it works.

Comment: I guess you acivate both profiles the same time. Maybe they stack if for example you activate the other by ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("standalone", "activemq"); or in the web.xml. Check that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your xsd declarations are using >= 3.1 versions for both `beans` and `util` namespaces:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd  ">
```

Most likely cause of error would be forgetting to set util declaration to 3.1, if as you say this works for other beans but not those declared using `util`.

Comment: Oh jings, I asked that ages ago and have moved jobs.  There is no way I can confirm if this answer is correct.

Comment: No problem, hopefully this will be useful to others experiencing this issue.

Comment: I just ran into the exact same problem and can confirm that @StephenHartley answer solves this.